# Make link expire after it's clicked in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The user will be emailed a link that is valid for two clicks & after it's clicked the second time, it won't work.

I already have my token & restricted access on the link. I also already have the 'expiration' 'after now' method in place right now but would like to replace it with a way to only make a link valid for only two clicks (maybe incrementing -- but idk).

How would I go about making a link valid for only two clicks in rails?

Thank you in advance

More info:

There will be many links. Is there a efficient way of doing this? Something that won't be "heavy" on my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way would be to have the link target a controller action. This action updates a database record each time the action is called. Before the value is '2', the action redirects the user to the intended destination. After '2', it sends the user somewhere else.

Comment: There will be many links. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? This way seems a bit "heavy"

Comment: @Jon If you want links to be accessible exactly twice, the only way to track this is to increment the number of visits in your database, which means you need a controller action somewhere that does that. Add a `visit_count` column to your links table (integer, default 0) and increment it whenever it is visited, then block access when `visit_count >= 2`.

Comment: AHHH PERFECT!! Thanks for the taking the time to help me @sscirrus